# Blender to trigger sound when objects touch each other

Tags: python

I am outlining a tooth from a dental model and my vertices are offset from the model. Is it possible to sound an alarm when the line hits the other model? In the photo you can see my line intersect the model, If I could get an alarm to go off?

[image]

Comment: Out of interest of the 23 answers to your 27 questions you have accepted none and voted only once?  It seems a very small "price to pay" for asking questions on bse.  As usual this question shows very little research effort.

Comment: I'm not sure where to vote, I will be happy to do so. Accepted none, not sure what you mean? I find it very difficult to research python script, especially in what I need it to do. You've been a great help, as others and this site is amazing. I have tried contacting you, however you can't message people her privately for paid work.